# Touchscreen does not work with TLP enabled

Tags: lenovo, touchscreen, tlp

I installed TLP on Ubuntu 18.04 on Lenovo Yoga 920. The touchscreen doesn't work if I enable tlp, but returns to normal if I disable it.

I tried to find an option for TLP to control this behavior using [tlpui](https://github.com/ZaMaZaN4iK/tlp-gui), but without success. Does anyone know how to continue having touchscreen with TLP enabled? Thank you.

This is the output of `xinput list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:15                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:15              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-touch:15                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-stylus:15                        id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-eraser:15                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-cursor:15                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ xwayland-keyboard:15                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:15.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #3 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:19.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #2 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
6b:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
6c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
```

I have checked for differences in `tlp stat` when the touchscreen is working and when it is not. One of the most notable difference is that under the summary for "runtime power management", all elements from `lspci` output are shown, with power control set to `auto` (with touchscreen working) and `on` when not.

Originally, this question was posted under Ubuntu 16.04, but I have since upgraded to 18.04 (and using Wayland) with the same problem as before. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you disable tlp, run the command `xinput list` and paste the results of that command into your question?

Comment: Oddly, I don't see the touch screen listed here.   Is it functional?

Comment: Yes, I doubled checked. Same output (even with sudo). Screen is functional, yes.

Comment: Ah - the device listed as the Wacom Finger Touch is your touchscreen.

Comment: OK - lets assume for a moment, that for some reason tlp is putting the wacom devices into autosuspend.  There is a way to prevent this, but you will need the ID of the wacom devices.  Please execute the command `lsusb` and append your question with the output of the command.

Comment: I've updated the question. The laptop has also fingerprint reader, but I believe that one doesn't work, so it is not listed on the xinput list, is it? Thank you.

Comment: K - the Wacom devices are not listed as USB devices - they must be PCI - can you add the output of `lspci` to your question? - ifthe fingerprint reader is broken, it will not be listed.

Comment: Gish - still not wacom devices!  Please edit `/etc/default/tlp` and look for the line "USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1" - change this to "USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0", save the file and execute `sudo service tlp restart` - lets see if this keeps power to your USB devices.

Comment: It turns out that after re-enabling tlp (and usb-autosuspend too), the touch screen is now working fine... I do not know what has changed, but it seems that everything is working fine now. Thanks a million for your help, and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I learn a little more every time I try to answer a question...

Comment: OK, not fixed yet. The following happens: if I boot only with battery, touchscreen works (with tlp enabled or disabled); if I boot on ac and tlp enabled touchscreen doesn't work; if I boot on ac and tlp disabled, touchscreen works.
I have tried disabling usb_autosuspend, but it has no effect when booting on ac and tlp enabled    :S

Comment: So try this - while on AC power source, execute `sudo tlp bat` which forces tlp to use the battery settings.  Lets see if that enables your touchscreen.

Comment: No, it doesn't help. I guess it happens during boot time. If I boot on battery and then connect ac, touchscreen keeps working.

Comment: I'm going to suggest you contact lenovo customer support - there is something odd going on there!  I have also seen a few blogs about this computer, linux, and that the fingerprint scanner does not work.

Comment: OK,  although in Windows it works fine all the time. I'll try to narrow down a little more the problem and come back with more info. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @CharlesGreen, I have updated the question after I have upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04. Do you have any new ideas about how to find the source of the problem? I am using Wayland at the moment, but touchscreen behavior is exactly as it was: it works if I boot with battery, and doesn't if I boot connected to AC. Again, TLP seems responsible. Thanks!

Comment: No clue, sorry.  I stopped using Wayland in favor of X though

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/gdm/custom.conf and uncoment "WaylandEnable=false"

Comment: I'm using lightdm rather than gdm (in Unity) so I found"/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf" rather than the file you mention. I added the line you suggested, saved and rebooted. However, it didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated to Ubuntu 18.04 and I am now using Wayland and gnome. However, using Wayland or Xorg has no influence on the touchscreen working properly.